# How customise create of variant value of product under odoo 12?

Tags: variant, odoo-12

In the product.template module I added a length / width variant as shown in the following figure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeI1U.png)

**I need to:** customize creation of values in column «Attribute Values» in form view which External id is product.product_template_only_form_view in odoo 12:

**For example:** if user enter value in column «attribute Value» value: «   *number1  * number2* » or value: «   *number1 x  space  number2* space  » or value: «space number1  x    number2  space   »  , i need function to trim spaces and set value «number1/number2» in this column!

**Other condition:** if number1 < number2 then i need to set value in column «attribute Value» like this «number2/number1» because we should have (length > width).

Here is a screenshot for this case: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GWpy.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
class valuesInherit(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'product.template'
      @api.depends('attribute_line_ids')
      def Change (self):
          if self.your_length_field and self.your_length_field:
              if if self.your_length_field > if self.your_width_field:
                   self.result_field = self.your_length_field/ your_length_field

              if self.your_length_field and self.your_length_field:
                  if if self.your_length_field < if self.your_width_field:
                   self.result_field = your_length_field/ self.your_length_field
```

Comment: Thanks you but in  form view i have only one attribute named «length/width», it can be named any name like «length-width» or «lengthwidth» or other else, value of this attribute is also one string value for example: «744 x  49» or «30 X   20» or «20 x 30» or ... (you can see screenshot above)